# Move a particular div to top programmatically in wordpress in all posts

Tags: html, css, mysql, wordpress

I have a particular div in all wordpress posts, I want to move them to the top , so that its the first paragraph. I have more than 3000 posts in the wordpress site. So moving each one isn't an option for me.
I tried this,

```
function add_this_script_footer(){
$specialDiv = document.getElementById("medtab");
$movedDiv = specialDiv;
$entryContent = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-content")[0];
entryContent.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', movedDiv);
specialDiv.remove();
}
```

add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer');

have added this to the code snippet plugin, but doesn't work.

This is the error am getting when adding it to functions.php

```
syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR)
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details like how that paragraph created dynamically or (static) entered in the editor. If unsure using CSS properties like `position: absolute`, `top: 0`, `left:0` you can do that but on the other hand please provide more details to avoid prediction answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write some simple javascript and place it in the footer to programmatically remove the `specified div` from your content and move it to the top of the content.

First add your JS to the footer. (This goes into your functions.php of your child theme. You can also use Code Snippets plugin to add it if are not using a child theme)

```
function add_this_script_footer(){ ?>
//YOUR JS CODE HERE
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer'); ?>
```

As you didn't share your code, I'm assuming that your special div has an id. In that case you can select it with.

```
var specialDiv = document.getElementById("your-div-id");
var movedDiv = specialDiv; // Copy moved Div to a new variable
```

You can then remove it using remove() method.

```
specialDiv.remove();
```

Finally, you can `insert` the `movedDiv` to the beginning of `entry-content` (Which should be the main content area div) by using `insertAdjacentElement()`

```
var entryContent = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-content")[0];
entryContent.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', movedDiv);
```

EDIT2: The problem was, `movedDiv` had to be "cloned" with `.cloneNode`

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () { ?>
<script>
  var specialDiv = document.getElementById("medtab");
  var movedDiv = specialDiv.cloneNode(true);
  var entryContent = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-content")[0];
  entryContent.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', movedDiv);
  specialDiv.remove();
</script>
<?php } );
```

Comment: You really know how to answer a question. Thank you so much. Will try at once. It's not like I didn't want to share the code. yes the div has an id.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code,. It doesn't work.

Comment: @hindisong.cc You need to wrap the javascript code in `<script>` and `</script>` tags in the add_this_script_footer() function.

Comment: I added the above code in functions.php., and I get this error. `Call to undefined function getElementById() in wp-content/themes/ta-newspaper/functions.php`

Comment: @hindisong.cc You mixed php code with javascript. I edited my answer and added sample code at the end of my answer. Please try that.

Comment: You mean `<?php` at the start and `?>` at the end, yes?

Comment: I already added my edited answer you can directly add it to functions.php

Comment: Thank you, It seems that the code works only half, the div is removed., but the div isn't copied to the top. [link](https://musicbono.com/news/parte-da-falesia-desabou-e-matou-casal-e-bebe-de-7-meses-na-praia-da-pipa/) I have posted the link.

Comment: @hindisong.cc I found the problem and edited my answer. `var movedDiv = specialDiv.cloneNode(true);`This line was changed

Comment: Worked, Awesome.